# How to hide standard interfaces from the default page WebService

Tags: web-services, delphi, datasnap

Some time ago I've been thinking about how to hide from default page of the web service the IAppServer and IAppServerSOAP interfaces and that appear by default. I know that my Webservice interface, has these interfaces as ancestors, but I believe pointless "see" these interfaces on the default page, as the client programs do not use them directly.

Is there any way to hide these interfaces and just keep our interface and others that were created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it!

To do so, all I had to do was edit the WebModule2DefaultHandlerAction method, i.e., the OnAction event handler of the DefaultHandler WebActionItem.

The final event handler looks like this now:

```
procedure TWEBMWebService.WebModule2DefaultHandlerAction(Sender: TObject; Request: TWebRequest; Response: TWebResponse; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  Conteudo: String;
begin
  WSHPWebService.ServiceInfo(Sender, Request, Response, Handled);

  Conteudo := Response.Content;
  try
    HideInterfaces(Conteudo,['IAppServer','IAppServerSOAP']);
  finally
    Response.Content := Conteudo;
  end;
end;
```

The HideInterfaces procedure follows:

```
procedure HideInterfaces(var aContent: String; aInterfaces: array of string);
var
  Intf: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  if Length(aInterfaces) = 0 then
    Exit;

  with TStringList.Create do
    try
      { Remove todos os enters }
      aContent := StringReplace(aContent,#13#10,' ',[rfreplaceAll]);

      { Separa tudo baseando-se nos TR }
      Text := StringReplace(aContent,'<tr>',#13#10'<tr>'#13#10,[rfreplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);
      Text := StringReplace(Text,'</tr>',#13#10'</tr>'#13#10,[rfreplaceAll,rfIgnoreCase]);

      { Neste ponto, cada linha do StringList contém ou <TR>, ou </TR>, ou o que
      houver entre os dois, então circulamos por cada interface que precisa ser
      ocultada }
      for Intf in aInterfaces do
      begin
        for i := 0 to Pred(Count) do
          if Pos(LowerCase(Intf),LowerCase(Strings[i])) > 0 then
            Break;

        { Se achou a interface, oculta a linha inteira de tabela, removendo do
        StringList i, i-1 e i+1 }
        if i < Count then
        begin
          Delete(i+1);
          Delete(i);
          Delete(i-1);
        end;
      end;

      aContent := Text;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
end;
```

The comments are in Portuguese, sorry, but it's easy to understand the code. If you like it and use it, please let me know and give me some credits, right ;)

I would like to thank you all for the valuable answers. Without your help I would never find the solution! Thank You All!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to alter the WSDL returned by the service.  I think there's a WSDL control, where you can override the WSDL response to either edit it, or substitute whatever you want.

Specifically, add a TWSDLHTMLPublish component to your WebModule form.  Use the OnBeforePublishingWSDL to write your own WSDL, like this:

```
procedure TWebModule2.WSDLHTMLPublish1BeforePublishingWSDL(
  const IntfName: WideString; var WSDL: WideString; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  WSDL := '<foo>bar</foo>';
  Handled := true;
end;
```

Comment: Well I do not know if there is a control to do that. If you have any more tips please share with us.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. This event handler only works on the WSDL generation and I need to change the initial page of the webservice. The page to change is like this http://www.weberinfo.com.br/weberservice/servidorws.exe

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Carlos!

But finally I found other approach . . . simply unregister the interface

```
InvRegistry.UnRegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IAppServer));
InvRegistry.UnRegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IAppServerSOAP));
InvRegistry.UnRegisterInterface(TypeInfo(IWSDLPublish));
```

Answer (score 0):

If your client applications do not need server to implement IAppServer (or IAppServerSOAP) then it is pointless to implement these. I expect you have implemented them - as you already said - because they are already implemented in ancestors of your objects - I expect it to be TSOAPDataModule.

So, instead of hiding them in the WSDL, i would suggest descending your server objects from a class that does not already introduce IAppServerxxxx. Which might be simple TDataModule (if you need a "container" object) or TInvokableClass.

Comment: Hello Thank you for the Answer. Take a look into this WS (this is not mine) http://www.weberinfo.com.br/weberservice/servidorws.exe. As you can see the IAppServer and IAppServerSOAP are being shown but in fact only the IFuncoes interface is used.